# HybridWebView .LoadContent doesn't LoadContent on ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Easy one of the day,  impress your friends!

Hybridwebview from xlabs - https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/HybridWebView

Attempting to load content as shown below.

Works fine on android, nothing shows up on ios using either str or str2.

Any ideas?

CSHARP

```
    void OnButtonStaticLoadClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        // doesnt load on ios
        string str = @"<html><body><h2>hello there</h2><div>four score and seven years ago </div></body></html>";
        string str2 = @"<!DOCTYPE html>" +
            @"<html>" +
            @"<body bgcolor='yellow'><h2>hello there</h2><div style='font-color:black'>four score and seven years ago</div>" +
            @"</body></html>";

        HybridWebView_Main.LoadContent(str2);
    }
```

XAML

```
<StackLayout>
  <Button x:Name="Button_LoadStatic" Text="Load Static HTML" Clicked="OnButtonStaticLoadClicked" />
  <controls:HybridWebView x:Name="HybridWebView_Main"
                      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                      BackgroundColor="Yellow"
                      HeightRequest="300" />
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason the renderer is not registered. Add

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(HybridWebView), typeof(HybridWebViewRenderer))]
```

in your iOS code and it will work.

Comment: Note : I added it just outside the namespace in my AppDelegate.cs in my HybridWebViewPlay.iOS project ...

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(HybridWebView), typeof(HybridWebViewRenderer))]

namespace HybridWebViewXLabs.iOS
{
    // The UIApplicationDelegate for the application. This class is responsible for launching the 
...

Comment: Yep, assembly attributes have to be placed before any other declaration in a file :)

Comment: I had this issue when compiling an UWP app with the .Net Native tool chain. Without the .Net Native tool chain, everything was fine; but as soon as I enabled it, the app only showed a blank page. Adding the renderer assembly solved the issue! Thanks!